# How to get next th of hideclass using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get next `th` of e-hide class using jQuery.  I want to get next th of the hidden column:

```
[
   th.e-headercell.e-default.e-filterrow,
   th.e-headercell.e-default.e-hide,
   th.e-headercell.e-default,
   th.e-headercell.e-default,
   th.e-headercell.e-default,
   th.e-headercell.e-default
]
```

Comment: can you explain question more clearly ?

Comment: Can you show your HTML, and explain which element is the current element and which one you want to get from it?

Comment: It looks like your current attempt (possibly pseudo-code) is going to cause you errors, since the hyphen/dash (`-`) isn't allowed in JavaScript names (hence the usual tendency to camelCase instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.next()` to get the next sibling element.

If you want to get the `th` after the one with class `.e-hide`:

```
$('th.e-hide').next();
```

If you want to get the next `th.e-hide` after current `th.e-hide`:

```
$('th.e-hide').next('th.e-hide');
```

If you want to get the next `th.e-hide` only if it has `.e-hide` class:

```
$('th').next('th.e-hide');
```